# Youtube is not open and chrome given error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Tags: youtube

4 days ago YouTube opened properly in Chrome and Firefox browsers. However, after 1 day, hitting YouTube URL on the browser, it does not open properly on the browser and gave me a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` error.

I have searched a lot on the internet but all solutions are not working for open youtube URL on the browser.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this problem only occurs with youtube, or do you know of other sites that would not answer? Opening `chrome://linux-proxy-config/`, do you see any proxy configured -- or more generally, do you use proxies, does the command `echo $http_proxy $HTTP_PROXY` returns with anything?

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with only youtube. No, I did not see any proxy configuration. But now I have resolved this problem with stop and start or restart DNS client-server. And now youtube is open properly. Thanks a lot, SYS for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

This error message suggests your DNS server does not know of that name - or does not respond.

You can open a terminal, and try out the following:

```
getent hosts youtube.com
```

Assuming it does not return with anything, you may be able to temporarily change your DNS resolver using

```
sudo sed -i 's|nameserver.*|nameserver 8.8.8.8|' /etc/resolv.conf
```

Or if no `nameserver` appears in that file, just add one:

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Thank you SYS for your reply, I have run both commands in the terminal and nameserver 8.8.8.8 appears in /etc/resolv.conf file and also restart my system, but I am still getting the same error which DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Please let me know the next solution.